# I'm trying to simply print out or write/display dynamically on a webpage whatever is in the title tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried a couple things like `document.title` and also giving the title tag and id and pulling the `innerHTML`.

`<script>document.getElementByID('tr').innerHTML="";</script>`

There's got to be a simpler way to do this and I'm just forgetting and can't figure it out atm.

my title tags are normal

```
<title></title>
```

or should i use the

```
<title id="tr"></title>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you can get the title tag content by

```
document.title
//or
document.querySelectorAll('title')[0].innerHTML;
```

But I'm not sure where you want to put it.  You are grabbing a  element now, but probably want to put it somewhere else;

In your HTML:

```
<h3 id='title'> </h3>
```

In your JavaScript

```
var title = document.title;
var domElem = document.getElementById('title');
//Add title to DOM element
domElem.innerHTML = title;
```

Comment: So how do i print it out on the screen?

Comment: You have a good answer. I do want to point out that innerText is not supported by all browsers. It appears to be more Mozilla based ones.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to innerHTML.  Cooking Good, the last thing in the post domElem.innerHTML is appending the titles text to an <h3> element with an ID of title.  you can also just do document.write(title) if thats all you are interested in...

Comment: Can you replicate in jsfiddle?

Comment: Nevermind.. i got it.. thank you.  haha.. that was weird.. i think it was just cached.